# python SimpleCookie distinguish error

Tags: python, cookies, cookielib

When i use python SimpleCookie object to pick up cookie from http headers, some exception occurs:

```
cookiestr = "a_em=[BU]co|12345678-901234567[DG]; Expires=Sat, 31 Dec 2016 17:09:50 GMT; Domain=.somesite.com; Path=/"
C = Cookie.SimpleCookie()
C.load(cookiestr)
print C
```

the output is:

```
Set-Cookie: a_em=; Domain=.somesite.com; expires=Sat,; Path=/
```

the cookie value and the cookie expires time is error!

how should i solve this?

Comment: The cookie string is not valid.

Comment: but web browser can handle it correctly and it is a real cookie from some site.

Comment: Web browsers are more error-tolerant than they should be. This is not a Python problem but a problem of the web server you are communicating with.

Answer (score 1):

RFC format for expires should be:

```
Expires=Sat, 31-Dec-2016 17:09:50 GMT
```

The full string should be (note quotes)

```
cookiestr = 'a_em="[BU]co|12345678-901234567[DG]"; Expires=Sat, 31-Dec-2016 17:09:50 GMT; Domain=.somesite.com; Path=/'
```

Comment: @macskuz: Is also not RFC-compliant.

Comment: @NiklasBaumstark  Thanks for the additional info. This now prints correct.